# How to open kendo window on custom buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am using kendo Grid with Custom buttons defined on it as follows

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<AdjustmentModel  >)ViewBag.Adjustments)
  .Name("AdjustmentsGrid")
  .DefaultConfiguration()
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height=100%" })
  .ToolBar(toolbar => {
      toolbar.Custom().Text("Search");
      toolbar.Custom().Text("Apply Adjustment");
      toolbar.Custom().Text("Clear");
  })
```

I want to open a kendo window on "Apply Adjustment" button. How do achieve it ?
Also how to provide grid on Kendo window ?

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
toolbar.Custom().Text("Apply Adjustment").HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "applyadjust"})
...

<div class="k-content">
    <div id="applyadjustmentwindow"></div>
</div>

<script>
var window = $("#applyadjustmentwindow"),
    applybtn = $("#applyadjust")
        .bind("click", function () {
            window.data("kendoWindow").open().center();                
        });

window.kendoWindow({
    title: "Apply Adjustment",
    actions: ["Minimize", "Maximize", "Refresh", "Close"],
    content: "URL to the action from which you are loading the html (can be partial view or plain html) on the window",        
    visible: false,        
    width: "50%"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it like this.

First declare a kendo window in div with display:none

```html
<div style="display:none">
  @(Html.Kendo().Window() .Name("MyWindowName") .Title("Test Window") .Content(@
  <text>
    <p>
      I am just for a demo
    </p>
  </text>) .Draggable() .Resizable() .Width(350) .Actions(actions => actions.Close()) )
</div>
```

Then add a button in Kendo Grid toolbar,

```html
toolBar.Custom().Text("Open Window").Url("javascript:OpenKendoWindow()");
```

Then add a javascript function

```js
function OpenKendoWindow(e) {
  $("#MyWindowName").data("kendoWindow").center(); // This will open the window on the center of the page
}
```

Thats it.